# Fillter/Sort the datas in ArrayStore ExtJS

Tags: sorting, extjs, filter

Using a Grid component, we wish to sort and filter rows using hidden values.
Sort and filters are working fine with visible values,
but we have now changed the format used for display, 
and we wish to use previous values for sort and filtering.

We are using the ArrayStore, without any proxy. 
We are looking for a solution on the client side, in JavaScript only
(no round trip to the server).

Comment: The `store.sort(..)` cannot work?

Comment: Yes, maybe. We found a thread in the Sencha forum and we are actually working about that. The store.sort(..) seems to be the right way for... Here is the link for the thread : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?48334-DISCUSS-Add-a-comparator-config-for-local-sort-on-Store

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ArrayStore

suggest look at methods sort() and filter(), others also can be usefull